# How do I calculate the terminal-to-terminal resistance and capacitance from an impedance matrix?

Tags: impedance, port

If I have a circuit with \$N\$ ports (and therefore \$2N\$ terminals), how can I calculate the terminal-to-terminal resistance and capacitance from a given impedance matrix \$Z\$? We can assume a shared ground for all ports.

Edit: I specifically mean the terminals of two *different* ports.

Comment: What have you tried? Tell us what you know about the problem so we don't start from ground zero.

Comment: I know the definition of the impedance matrix is that the voltage across port \$n\$ is \$V_n = \sum_a Z_{na} I_a\$, and that the current \$I_a\$ going into port \$a\$ is equal to the current going out of that port.